# $f(m+n+1) = f(m) + f(n)$. Show $f(x) = x + 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

$f(m+n+1) = f(m) + f(n)$. Show $f(x) = x + 1$ if $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R$ and $f$ is countinous.

I was able easily to show it for the integers and a few specific fractions but I am stuck at showing it for all fractions. A hint would be appreciated. Also, when proving it for all reals is it enough to say that rationals are dense in the reals and hence by the continuity condition it follows that all reals follow $f(x) = x+1$ since any real may be approximated arbitrarily well by a rational.

Comment: Doesn't $f(x) = x+1$ trivially satisfy the relation if you plug it in? $(m + n + 1) + 1 = (m + 1) + (n + 1)$.

Comment: If $f(x)=x+1$ is a solution isn't $f(x)=(x+1)/2$ also a solution?  So how can one single out the $f(x)=x+1$ solution?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the boundary condition $f(0) = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there are more general solutions. A nice approach is to set $g(x)=f(x-1)$. Then

$$g(x+y)=f(x+y-1)=f((x-1)+(y-1)+1)=f(x-1)+f(y-1)=g(x)+g(y)$$

which is [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation). You can then try to show that $g(p/q)=(p/q)g(1)$ for all rational $p/q$.

To answer your specific question at the end: any dense set is fine - two continuous functions that are equal on a dense set must be equal everywhere.